Best Response and Nash Equilibria within a boundary
Let X and Y be the set of the strategies of two players. Let $X = Y = \{ v \mid v \in \mathbb{R} , 0 \leq v \leq 10 \}$. Let the utility functions of the two players be:
$$f(x,y) = -2x^2 - 4xy + 6 $$
$$g(x,y) = -y^2 + 4xy - 4y$$
Find the best response of the 2 players and the Nash equilibria of the game.
My solution:
I did differentiation f(x,y) with respect to x and g(x,y) with respect to y and got
$$\frac{df}{dx}: x = -y$$
$$\frac{dg}{dy}: y = 2x - 2 $$
Solving the equation, I got $(x^*,y^*) = (\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{2}{3})$, but the nash equilibria isn't within the bound. Is there no solution for this question, or is there a way to find another nash equilibria for this 2 utility function?

When solving the optimization problem, you have to account for the constraints; you are looking for the best replies within the strategy sets. You can check that $(0,0)$ is a Nash equilibrium.

The confusion here coming from the fact that the maximum value of the $f(x, y)$ function is not reached on one of its extrema, but on its boundary. Consider this:
$$
f(x, y) = -2x^2-4xy + 6 = -2(x^2 + 2xy) + 6 = -2(x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - y^2) + 6 =\\
= -2(x^2+2xy+y^2) + 2y^2 + 6 = -2(x+y)^2 + 2y^2+6
$$
If you fix some value of $y$, graph of $f(x, y)$ is a parabola with vertex in $(-y, 2y^2 + 6)$. Thus, for any non-negative $y$ $f(x, y)$ is decreasing when $x = 0$  (and for any $x$ greater than $0$). This means that when $y \ge 0$, $f(x, y)$ reaches its maximum value on $[0;10]$ at $x = 0$. As the condition $y \ge 0$  is always true, $a = 0$ is the best response for player $A$ no matter what player $B$ is doing.
All that is left to do is to find $B$'s best response on $A$'s $a = 0$. You can easily check, that it is $b = 0$. Thus, $(0, 0)$ is the only Nash equilibrium.
